# Specifying minor TLS version when using curl

Tags: curl, tls

Is there a way to specify curl to use a specific TLS version? Like 1.1 or 1.2? I can see only sslv3 and tlsv1 options in command help. I took latest src and compiled it with openssl 1.0.1e. Still dont see a direct option in help. Is there any other way to set it?

Comment: I don't see any options for setting minor TLS version either. Also see [this thread](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2013-04/0371.html): "That's because, when libcurl is configured to use TLSv1, it will automatically use the highest version number supported by your TLS library, and downgrade to TLS 1.0 if the server doesn't support 1.1 or 1.2. There's no separate option here because, until a serious problem is found in 1.0, there doesn't need to be a separate option."

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Curl has options to control the TLS version used. At the date of the last revision to this answer, if you want to specify that TLS 1.2 is used but not 1.1 or 1.3 etc, you need something like

```
curl --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 ...
```

Answer last checked on 2024-03-13 and still applies for curl version 8.6.0

---

There have been several relevant changes in Curl since the original question was asked.

### Version 7.54.0

Since version 7.54.0 the behaviour has changed, see [nelsonda's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1510289/52492).

Options like `--tlsv1.2` now specify a *minimum* version that is to be used, they no longer specify the *exact* version to be used.

To specify an exact version to be used you likely have to also specify a value for `--tls-max`

```
curl --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 ...
```

---

### Version 7.52.0

Version 7.52.0 introduced `--tlsv1.3` in addition to the other options listed below.

---

### Version 7.34.0

Since version 7.34.0, Curl has options `--tlsv1.0`, `--tlsv1.1` and `--tlsv1.2` for this purpose.

The [manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) said

> -1, --tlsv1
>
> (SSL) Forces curl to use TLS version 1.x when negotiating with a remote TLS server. You can use options --tlsv1.0, --tlsv1.1, and --tlsv1.2 to control the TLS version more precisely (if the SSL backend in use supports such a level of control).
>
> ...
>
> --tlsv1.2
>
> (SSL) Forces curl to use TLS version 1.2 when negotiating with a remote TLS server. (Added in 7.34.0)

---

Comment: Useful updates.

Answer (score 16):

Curl's behavior has changed!

For versions prior to 7.54.0, [RedGrittyBrick's answer](https://superuser.com/a/976171/130248) remains correct. For version of curl after 7.54.0 the options `--tlsv1.0`, `--tlsv1.1` and `--tlsv1.2` set the *minimum* version of TLS that curl will use. To specify the maximum use `--tls-max <VERSION>`.

From the [manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--tls-max):

> #### [`--tls-max <VERSION>`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--tls-max)
>
> (SSL) VERSION defines maximum supported TLS version. The minimum
> acceptable version is set by tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2 or tlsv1.3.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to `--tlsvX.Y`/`--sslvZ`, which put a hard limit to what protocols curl would choose, you may use `--tls-max x.y` to softly control protocol negotiation.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the --cipher option [see manpage](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and [OpenSSL docs](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html). You should be able to provide a cipher list that will force certain versions.