# Is there a difference between curl --tlsv1 and --tlsv1.0?

Tags: curl, tls

The Curl man page lists `-1 --tlsv1` and separately lists `--tlsv1.0` along with v1.1 and v1.2.

The descriptions are:

`-1, --tlsv1
              (SSL) Forces curl to use TLS version 1 when negotiating with a remote TLS server.`

And later:

`--tlsv1.0
              (SSL) Forces curl to use TLS version 1.0 when negotiating with a remote TLS server.  (Added in 7.34.0)`

Is there a difference between these tlsv1 and tlsv1.0 options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the [curl help code in github](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/src/tool_help.c), we see

> -1, --tlsv1         Use >= TLSv1 (SSL)
>
> --tlsv1.0       Use TLSv1.0 (SSL)
>
> --tlsv1.1       Use TLSv1.1 (SSL)
>
> --tlsv1.2       Use TLSv1.2 (SSL)

Thus, --tlsv1 uses any of 1.0, 1.1, or 1.2, while the other three use a specific one.

For increased security, use --tlsv1.2 specifically.

Comment: The behaviour has changed in recent curl versions, and both now indeed do the same. See this answer: https://superuser.com/a/976171/1183051